# Assembly languaje, base pointer

Tags: pointers, assembly, turbo-c

i was reading an example in assembly languaje, and i have a little doubt. We were using assembly only on our programs, but the last unit on the semester it's to merge it with turbo c (in-line assembly), and reading the code, there's a part which i don't quite get it:
Here's the assembly part:

```
dosseg
.model small 
.code 
public _myputchar 
_myputchar PROC
    push bp 
    mov bp,sp
    mov dl,[bp+4]
    mov ah,2
    int 21h 
    pop bp 
    ret 
_myputchar ENDP
END
```

And here's the C part:

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern void myputchar( char x );
char *str={"Hola Mundo\n"};
void main ( void )
{
    while(*str)
    myputchar(*str++);
    getchar();
}
```

So, it's pretty straight forward, and the program works, but, what i don't get, it's the assembly code. The problem is, Why the base pointer (bp) it's pointing to +4? (mov dl,[bp+4]), I would think that you only had to mov dl,bp but i don't get why +4. If someone can help we, that would be really apretiated!. (in the include section i put the "" Because the formating tools it's giving me such headech -_-!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument (`x`) is pushed onto the stack before calling the function. After this, the `call` instruction will push the return address (2 bytes in this case) onto the stack, and the `push bp` at the beginning of the function will push another 2 bytes onto the stack.

So by now you've pushed 2+2 == 4 more bytes onto the stack after the argument. Since the stack grows downward that means that to get the argument you have to offset the pointer by +4 bytes.

Comment: Well gee thanks! I was sure it was something super easy, but i wasn't geting it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The starting address of the string you want to print is at [bp + 4]. The current stack pointer is [bp]. Remember, the stack grows down.